# Parse JSON to Object fails

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am trying to parse JSON into an object, yet it keeps failing.

I keep on getting the error:

> The type or namespace name 'DataContractJsonSerializer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

But so far all the references have been added, but somehow it is still not functioning.

Am I doing the right thing here?

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
public Json_Connection ()
{
    // Create a request for the URL. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
            "http://10.190.80.248/WebService/webservice.asmx/getStudentID?id=1");

    // If required by the server, set the credentials.
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);

    // Clean up the streams and the response.
    XmlSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (Json.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(Json) });
    Json flippo = (Json)serializer.Deserialize (reader);
}
```

**I use a MAC,so no windows folders or .net on this mac**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization to your project.  This dll should be included as part of the standard Xamarin distribution.

Alternatively, you may want to try using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net/), which is a great Json package available for Xamarin.